# No connection possible via Ad-Hoc-Network

Tags: windows-8.1, ad-hoc-network

I created an Ad-Hoc-Network on Windows 8.1 using the commands

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=”DESIRED_NETWORK_NAME” key=”YOUR_PASSWORD”
netsh.exe wlan start hostednetworkname
```

But when I want to use this network via my phone or my tablet, I have no internet connection. Did I forget something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many are facing the same issue. Check out this [thread](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-networking/windows-81-ad-hoc-not-showing/5d75d887-ff59-425e-a480-9f80ada63627) at Microsoft's Answer:

> Instead of connecting to others ad-hoc, try to create a hosted network
>   through netsh command line application. Once the new network created,
>   let other device connect to it.